# What can be done to improve/increase the amount of Close Votes reviews and to stop <3k user’s close flags ageing away?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close

At the time of writing this I am below 3k rep, so I can’t vote to close but I flag to close.

I have noticed this issue quite a lot:

- I review a post in the First Posts queue/Triage queue and flag for closure
- The flag stays being marked as *pending*
- The flag ages away without a Close Vote review and the poor quality question remains on the site

On average, 50% of my closure flags age away.

Examples:

- [SLComposeViewControllerResult callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62551969/slcomposeviewcontrollerresult-callback) (flagged less than 30 minutes after posted, left in the CV queue for 4 days [with no review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/26499790))
- [Issue with Rich Editor Control using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62773858/issue-with-rich-editor-control-using-jquery) (flagged soon after this was posted but question was stuck in the queue and then left it)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62244909/ms-teams-support-in-uae (same thing again)

In these cases, a user clicking *Unsalvageable* in the Triage queue (by flagging to close instead of voting to close) or flagging to close in the First Posts queue is having the same outcome as *Looks OK* and *No Action Needed* - the question stays open.

What can be done to the CV queue to stop affecting the quality of existing reviews in Triage and the First Posts review queue?

---

**Note**: Lately, to start expediting CV requests, I have started posting them in [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), which helps *a lot* but is not a permanent solution.

Comment: It is increasingly more difficult for enthusiastic newbies on SO to get rep. Some tend to want it at all cost without wanting to earn it. I agree that rep to close votes should be improved

Comment: @linkonabe I think the best way to earn reputation is to become better at what one does. Then one can answer more Questions. Of course even experts can write bad answers, so that is also a skill one needs to develop.